# ESME parameters confirmation

Tags: smpp, jsmpp, opensmpp

we are writing a component which sends message to a device thru one 3rd party interface.

i did used smpp client code to do that, but i want to make sure that what ever parameters i am passing is correct. 
anyone correct me on below parameters if i am wrong.

sender = // 3rd party IP address

destination = // sim number which i want to send sms to it

ipAddress = "smpp.xyzwireless.com"; // provided by 3rd party

port = 2775;

systemId = srini // provided by 3rd party

password = srini // provided by 3rd party

and the with above details Bind() method will execute first then submit() and unBind() methods.

after you confirmed above parameters, could you confirm below possibility.

i want to keep the connection between ESME and SMSC alive for some long time. for that i am doing enquireLink() method.

i am placing this enquireLink method inside Timer() of java so it keeps check the connection for every 45 seconds and re-establish the disconnection time to next 60  seconds from time of enquireLink.

Am i thinking anything wrong here? correct me guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please have a look at my answer and provide me with some feedback so that we could close this issue for you and for anyone who might come across this in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If JSMPP implements opensmpp the same way other os-libs do, then `sender` will stand for an A-number — alpha-numeric or simply numeric string of no more that 11 bytes that represents your identity to a recipient.

You can think of it as your ESME sim number.

You might also need to specify source_TON and source_NPI to help SMSC understand the contents of this `sender` field.

The rest of your parameters and methods seem fine.